# Git Merge previous commit

Tags: git, merge

So I think I have a simple thing I want to do. I have 2 branches. In "master" I want to merge branch "feature", but I don't want the latest change from "feature".

Currently

```
--M0--M1--M2
    \
      F0--F1--F2
```

Want:

```
--M0--M1--M2--M3
    \        /
      F0--F1--F2
```

Sorry I don't know how to diagram it, but my master head (M2) should get all changes up to F1 and essentially, it should be equivalent to:

```
--M0--M1--M2--M3
               \
                F1--F2
```

So How do I do this merge so that the master branch doesn't pick up the latest F2 commit?

**EDIT:** Background on the issue.

I have a master branch and started a feature branch. Then I made a change (A) in the feature branch that should have been in the master branch. Then I made a change (B) in the feature branch (which belongs there). I would have liked change (A) to be in master, feature branch to branch from there, and change (B) to remain in the feature branch.

In the future, the feature branch may pick up changes from master. Then, when the feature is done, it will merge back into master and that branch can be deleted.

Comment: You always can reference the commit in question directly via it's SHA-1 key which you should see in the log. Alternativly you can make a relative reference, for example like `F2^` or `F2~1`.

Comment: Zeeker's answer covers the question that you asked.  However, you don't mention if you plan on continuing to develop on 'feature', and if you ever plan to merge 'feature' into 'master' again, which would require a slightly more involved answer.

Comment: @AndrewC good point. Matt, just tell me if my answer doesn't completly cover your scenario. I'll happily edit my answer to provide everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a commit history - like you provided in your example - with the following branch references.

```
--M0--M1--M2 <- master
   \
    F0--F1--F2 <- feature
```

**Some Background**

In git you don't merge branches but rather commits. Each commit has a reference on it's parent commit and this is how your history is build. Branches are merely are reference on a specific commit.

Merge commits are defined as commits which have more than one parent commit.

**Reference the commit**

This means you just have to provide a reference on the commit you want to merge. So the merge command would look like this:

```
# Make sure you are on the master branch when executing the command
git merge <reference-on-F1>
```

There are two easy ways to reference the commit.

1. You can make a direct reference via it's *SHA-1* hash. This hash gets printed in a short format in your log output. (`git merge abc123`)
2. You can make a relative reference from another commit, for example from a branch reference. There exist two major syntaxes to create relative references. The `^` and `~` operator.
   While the `^` operator directly addresses the next parent the `~` can address a parent commit which lies further behind (while `master~3` is equivalent to `master^^^`).
   In your case this would lead to `git merge feature^`.

If you want to learn more about git references than take a look at the [Git Revision Selection chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) of the gitpro book.

**Edit** As Andrew correctly noticed I didn't talk about the "argument" the `^` takes. I left it out on purpose, since it isn't crucial to the question. If you still are interested  you can find everything under the link I provided.

Comment: Info is all good except your description of the ^ syntax.  That is used to specify the parent number in a merge commit.  For special case of 'first parent' it is identical to the ~ syntax.

Comment: @AndrewC I know, but I wanted to keep it simple, since this information isn't crucial in this case. But nethertheless good that you noticed.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know. Thanks for all the info here, still learning the details of branching and merging and this helps!

Comment: @Matt I can highly recommend the [gitpro book](http://git-scm.com/book) which is completly free. It was the resource I used when I started using git, and it really covers a lot of topics. If you just want to learn more about branching take a look at the [Branching chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching).